# C++ class overloaded operator `()` called in template is not able to change member variable's value

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, operators, member

I met a problem when working with templates and overloaded operators in C++.

I want to create a class `Foo` with an overloaded operator `()`, and I also want to change the value of a private member variable `bar_` of class `Foo` inside the overloaded `()`, and keep that value for later use. I have to finish this with a template: I will pass an object of the `Foo` class into the template, and then call it with the object's name (i.e. run the overloaded `()` operator) inside the template. Later, I will call the `GetBar` public member function on the object to get the value of `bar_`.

In the following minimal reproducible example, the value of the private member variable `bar_` is changed to 2 in the overloaded `()` operator, and is called in the template. However, when I tried to get the value of `bar_` later outside the template using the `GetBar` public member function, it gives me the value 1, which is the initial value given to the variable `bar_` in the constructor. Thus, the value change in the `()` operator doesn't work.

Does anyone have an idea what is happening here? I am not sure why the value change is not saved in the variable.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

using std::unordered_map;

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::unordered_map;

class Foo {
 public:
  Foo() : bar_(1) {}

  void operator()() {
    bar_ = 2;
    std::cout << "print in the operator: bar_ = " << bar_ << std::endl;
    return;
  }

  size_t GetBar() {
    return bar_;
  }

 private:
  int bar_;
};

template <typename T>
int NodeWalk(T action) {
  action();
  return 0;
}

int main()
{
    Foo obj;
    NodeWalk(obj);
    cout << "print out the operator: bar_ = " << obj.GetBar() << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
print in the operator: bar_ = 2
print outside the operator: bar_ = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `int NodeWalk(T action)` takes the parameter *by value*, which means that the first print from your `operator()()` is called from a **copy**, which *did* alter the value of `bar_`. But once the function ends, the copy is destroyed. The original object declared in `main()` is unaltered, which is why you see the original value when you try to print again.

If you want the original to be altered, pass the parameter *by reference*, like this: `int NodeWalk(T& action)`.

Comment: Oh I thought I understood the value and reference but then messed them up...thank you so much!